# ¿Por qué me sobrescribe el objeto anterior al ingresar uno nuevo dentro de un arreglo?

Tags: javascript, dom

**Intento crear un formulario donde los datos ingresados se muestren en un tabla.**
*Al intentar realizar el primer registro lo hace correctamente, pero los siguientes sobreescriben los anteriores con el registro actual[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]*

```
//Arreglo de personas
const arregloPersonas = [];
//Objetos de personas
const persona={
  id: 0,
  nombre: '',
  primerApellido:'',
  segundoApellido: '',
  edad:0,
  correo:''
}
```

**Obtengo los datos del formulario**

```
//Obtener datos de formulario
function obtnerDatos(){
  let valorNombre = document.getElementById('nombre-input').value;
  let valorPrimerApellido = document.getElementById('apellido-prim-input').value;
  let valorSegundoApellido = document.getElementById('apellido-seg-input').value;
  let valoredad = document.getElementById('edad-input').value;
  let valorCorreo = document.getElementById('correo-input').value;
```

**Intento añadir el objeto a el arreglo**

```
  //Relaciona los datos con el objeto creado
  persona.nombre = valorNombre;
  persona.primerApellido = valorPrimerApellido;
  persona.segundoApellido = valorSegundoApellido;
  persona.edad = valoredad;
  persona.correo = valorCorreo;
  //Agrega el objeto con datos al arreglo
  arregloPersonas.push(persona);
}
```

Comment: Puedes crear un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) para crear un [repro] en tu pregunta. Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Estaria faltando que muestres el inconveniente, ¿como insertas los nuevos valores?

Comment: Creo que estás metiendo en el array elementos que son referencias al mismo objeto, por tanto, cada vez que cambias las propiedades del objeto, el efecto es que se las cambias a todos los elementos del array. Pero, ya te digo, no es porque realmente se las cambies a todos, es que todos son el mismo. Deberías hacerlo con una clase instanciable y crear una instancia para cada elemento que vas a añadir al array. O quizá añadirlos al array como copias.

Comment: Si cada ves que rellenas los campos usas el mismo objeto `persona` y solo le cambias los valores (ej `persona.edad = valoredad`) antes de insertarlo a tu array entonces ahí está tu problema. En javascript, y en otros lenguajes también, cuando utilizas variables esta puede ser utilizada como referencia o como valor. [Aquí](https://medium.com/laboratoria-developers/por-valor-vs-por-referencia-en-javascript-de3daf53a8b9) te dejo una explicación que encontré al respecto. Cuento corto, en vez de modificar el objeto persona, debes crear uno nuevo para insertarlo al array.

Answer (score 3):

Cuando haces el push de un objeto a un array, estas insertando la referencia al objeto, no una copia, siempre que modifiques el objeto "original" se van a modificar todos los lugares en donde esté la referencia.

```js
const array = [];

const obj = {"a":1}

array.push(obj); // <-- insertamos la referencia de objeto dentro de array

obj.a = 2; // <-- modificamos obj, tambien modifica obj dentro de array

console.log(array);
```

Dicho de otra forma, en tu caso existe una sola persona, que vas modificando. Para crear personas distintas, es decir objetos distintos, tienes que crear un objeto nuevo cada vez. Una forma es hacer una clase y crear instancias, otra puede ser creando muchas veces el mismo objeto:

```js
const arregloPersonas = [];

function agregaPersona(idx) {

  const persona = { //<-- Se crea un objeto nuevo cada vez que llamamos a la función
    id: idx
  }

  arregloPersonas.push(persona);

}


agregaPersona(1);
agregaPersona(2);
agregaPersona(3);

console.log(arregloPersonas);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me habia contemplado esa forma.

Answer (score 0):

Aca te dejo un pequeño ejemplo con clases para que te sea mas simple la labor.

```js
class Persona {
  constructor() {
    [...document.querySelectorAll("input")].forEach(input =>
      this[input.name] = input.value
    )
  }
}

class ListaPersonas {
  constructor() {
    this.listadoPersonas = []
  }
  agregarPersona(destino) {
    this.listadoPersonas.push(new Persona())
    this.imprimirPersonas(destino)
  }

  imprimirPersonas(destino) {
    //aca tenes que hacer tu propia estructura.
    document.getElementById(destino).innerHTML = this.listadoPersonas.map(persona => JSON.stringify(persona))
  }
}

let listadoPersonas = new ListaPersonas()
```

```html
Nombre_: <input name="nombre" type="text" /><br/> 
Apellido1: <input name="primerApellido" type="text" /><br/> 
Apellido2: <input name="segundoApellido" type="text" /><br/> 
Edad____: <input name="edad" type="number" /><br/> 
Correo__: <input name="correo" type="text" /><br/>

<button onclick="listadoPersonas.agregarPersona('destinoPersonas')"> Agregar al Array</button>

<div id="destinoPersonas"> </div>
```

Comment: Acoplar el constructor de la clase al DOM no me parece una buena idea, si en algún momento cambia el HTML habría que modificar la clase. Un constructor con los 5 parámetros es agnóstico a la forma de obtener los datos

Comment: estoy de acuerdo, es un ejemplo, siempre deberias recibir el destino como una variable, pero queria limitar el largo del ejemplo. y la clase persona persona podria tener algun otro metodo que sea util para el caso.

Comment: ahi lo modifique.

Answer (score 0):

> Creando a cada  objeto y luego  agregándolo al final del array de
> objeto

s

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title> HTML5</title>
  <script languaje="JavaScript">
    const arregloPersonas = [];
    function myFunction() {

      let valorNombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
      let valorPrimerApellido = document.getElementById('primerApellido').value;
      let valorSegundoApellido = document.getElementById('segundoApellido').value;
      let valoredad = document.getElementById('edad').value;
      let valorCorreo = document.getElementById('correo').value;

      const persona = {
        nombre: valorNombre,
        primerApellido: valorPrimerApellido,
        segundoApellido: valorSegundoApellido,
        edad: valoredad,
        correo: valorCorreo
      }
      console.log(persona);
      myFunction1(persona)
    }


    function myFunction1(persona) {
      // Agregamos a la persona 
      arregloPersonas.push(persona);
      console.log(arregloPersonas)
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  Nombre_: <input name="nombre" type="text" id='nombre' /><br />
  Apellido1: <input name="primerApellido" type="text" id='primerApellido' /><br />
  Apellido2: <input name="segundoApellido" type="text" id='segundoApellido' /><br />
  Edad____: <input name="edad" type="number" id='edad' /><br />
  Correo__: <input name="correo" type="text" id='correo' /><br />
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>


</body>

</html>
```